# How can I store order of photos?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage which loads from server some photos and a Photoswipe gallery with photos loaded from server.
The webpage retrieves images using ajax and list them as shown in the screenshot:

**Before sorting**
[image: before sorting]

I want to drag the divs and to sort them (Already did using jquery ui) and it looks as shown in the next screenshot:

**after sorting**
[image: after sorting]

After dragging, I want the photos to appear sorted in the gallery. How can I do this?

This is the code I wrote to get the img src. It works perfectly, but I don't know how to connect it with something that could sort the photos in gallery.

```
$(function(){
                $(".uploadedImages").sortable({stop:function(event, ui){
                        var photoDivs = $(".uploadedImages").children();
                        for(i = 1; i < photoDivs.length; i++){
                            var child = photoDivs[i];
                            console.log($(child).children()[0].src);
                        }
                }
                });
                $(".uploadedImages").disableSelection();
            });
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want a persistent sorting in the gallery by drag and drop?

Comment: dear fellow romanian what do you mean by **I want the photos to appear sorted in the gallery**  ?

Comment: @appleapple I've already used it.

Comment: @NMonst4 yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially store the order in a cookie, but that means the order will be personal to each users browser.

Alternatively, if your site is backed by a database and you have stored the URL and being arranged by the browser, then you could have an event that on drag completed, it sends up the new order to the database.

This'll persist the order and give each user of the site the same experience

I can expand on advice above if you'd like.

Cheers,

P

Comment: Yes, the site is backed by a database. How can I store? A new table called something like "photos" with 2 columns, src and position? I would be thankful.